# phonegap: function not getting called

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm learning phonegap by making a simple t-do app.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-dos</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='loadToDoList()'>
        <input type='button' value='Add To-do' onclick='createNewToDo()'/>
        <input type='button' value='Remove completed To-dos' onclick='removeCompletedTasks()'/>
        <br/><br/>
        <table id='dataTable' width='100%' border='1'>
        </table>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
(function() {
  var addTableRow, checkboxClicked, deleteAllRows, deleteSelectedRow, loadToDoList, saveToDoList, viewSelectedRow;

  window.rowID = 0;

  saveToDoList = function() {
    var checkBoxState, chkbox, i, row, rows, table, textValue, textbox, todoArray, _i, _len;
    todoArray = {};
    checkBoxState = 0;
    textValue = '';
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    rows = table.rows;
    if (rows.length > 0) {
      i = 0;
      for (_i = 0, _len = rows.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        row = rows[_i];
        chkbox = rows.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if ((chkbox != null) && chkbox.checked === true) {
          checkBoxState = 1;
        } else {
          checkBoxState = 0;
        }
        textbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];
        textValue = textbox.value;
        todoArray["row" + (i++)] = {
          check: checkBoxState,
          text: textValue
        };
      }
    } else {
      todoArray = null;
    }
    return window.localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(todoArray));
  };

  loadToDoList = function() {
    var i, key, theList, val, _results;
    theList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('todoList'));
    deleteAllRows();
    if (theList !== null && theList !== 'null') {
      i = 0;
      _results = [];
      for (key in theList) {
        val = theList[key];
        _results.push(addTableRow(theList["row" + (i++)], true));
      }
      return _results;
    }
  };

  deleteAllRows = function() {
    var i, rowCount, table, _i;
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    rowCount = table.rows.count;
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= rowCount ? _i < rowCount : _i > rowCount; i = 0 <= rowCount ? ++_i : --_i) {
      table.deleteRow(i);
      rowCount--;
      i--;
    }
    return saveToDoList();
  };

  viewSelectedRow = function(todoTextField) {
    return alert(todoTextField.value);
  };

  deleteSelectedRow = function(deleteButton) {
    deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild();
    return saveToDoList();
  };

  checkboxClicked = function() {
    var chkbox, row, rows, table, textbox, _i, _len, _results;
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    rows = table.rows;
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = rows.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      row = rows[_i];
      chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      textbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];
      if ((chkbox != null) && chkbox.checked === true && (textbox != null)) {
        textbox.style.setProperty('text-decoration', 'line-through');
      } else {
        textbox.style.setProperty('text-decoration', 'none');
      }
      _results.push(saveToDoList());
    }
    return _results;
  };

  addTableRow = function(todoDictionary, appIsLoading) {
    var cell1, cell2, element1, element2, row, rowCount, table;
    rowID++;
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    rowCount = table.rows.length;
    row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    element1 = document.createElement('input');
    element1.type = 'checkbox';
    element1.name = 'chkbox[]';
    element1.checked = todoDictionary['check'];
    element1.setAttribute('onclick', 'checkboxClicked()');
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    element2 = document.createElement('input');
    element2.type = 'text';
    element2.name = 'txtbox[]';
    element2.size = 16;
    element2.id = 'text' + rowID;
    element2.value = todoDictionary['text'];
    element2.setAttribute('onchange', 'saveToDoList()');
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
    checkboxClicked();
    saveToDoList();
    if (!appIsLoading) {
      return alert('Task added successfully');
    }
  };

  window.createNewToDo = function() {
    var todo, todoDictionary;
    todoDictionary = {};
    todo = prompt('To-Do', '');
    if (todo != null) {
      if (todo === '') {
        return alert('To-Do can\'t be empty');
      } else {
        todoDictionary = {
          check: 0,
          text: todo
        };
        return addTableRow(todoDictionary, false);
      }
    }
  };

  window.removeCompletedTasks = function() {
    var chkbox, i, rowCount, table, _i;
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= rows ? _i < rows : _i > rows; i = 0 <= rows ? ++_i : --_i) {
      chkbox = table.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if ((chkbox != null) && chkbox.checked === true) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
        i--;
        rowCount--;
      }
    }
    saveToDoList();
    return alert('Completed tasks were removed');
  };

}).call(this);
```

My `createNewToDo` function works fine, since I'm able to create new todos. But when I check a todo and click on the remove button, nothing happens. Why is my `removeCompletedTasks` function not being called?

Comment: It would be cool if you provide a Fiddle to see your code in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the provided code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ8G9/).  The primary reason that I can see for removeCompletedTasks failing is that rows is undefined.   After that is fixed, the other errors are caused by the methods you have defined only being in scope inside of the outside function.  Once it completes, they are gone and cannot be called.

Each of the methods need to have window. before them.  Then the saveToDoList needs a little work.  the table method doesn't work, just go directly for the rows.  Once you have the row you want use that reference.

```
window.saveToDoList = function() {
   var checkBoxState, chkbox, i, row, rows, textValue, textbox, todoArray, _i, _len;
   todoArray = {};
   checkBoxState = 0;
   textValue = '';
   rows = document.getElementById('dataTable').rows;
   if (rows.length > 0) {
     i = 0;
     for (_i = 0, _len = rows.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
       row = rows[_i];
       chkbox = row.childNodes[0];
       if ((chkbox != null) && chkbox.checked === true) {
         checkBoxState = 1;
       } else {
         checkBoxState = 0;
       }
       textbox = row.childNodes[1];
       textValue = textbox.value;
       todoArray["row" + (i++)] = {
         check: checkBoxState,
         text: textValue
       };
     }
   } else {
     todoArray = null;
   }
   return window.localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(todoArray));
};
```

With that method working, now the removeCompletedTasks needs some fine tuning.  The loop can be simplified to a simple for loop.  Removing the row is done by getting it fresh each time, I know this is slower, but at least chrome returns a function for table the way it was.  To get the checkbox, one more level of children needed peeling, and now it works.

```
  window.removeCompletedTasks = function() {
    var chkbox, i, rowCount, rows;
    rows = document.getElementById('dataTable').rows;
    rowCount = rows.length;
    for (i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {
      chkbox = rows[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
      if ((chkbox != null) && chkbox.checked === true) {
        document.getElementById("dataTable").deleteRow(i);
        --i;
        --rowCount;
      }
    }
    saveToDoList();
    return alert('Completed tasks were removed');
  };
```

Check out the new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38WPk/) for the working example.